# Ширина кнопки, js

Tags: javascript, dom

Напишите, пожалуйста, как правильно менять ширину кнопки в DOM.
Я просто не очень силён в js.

Comment: как бы не js  нужен а css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сильон бульон .

Для изменения внешнего вида элементов DOM используйте прямое изменение CSS стиля вот так:

```js
// изменение ширины кнопки с id "button-id"
document.getElementById('button-id').style.width = '150px'; // новая ширина
```

И на будущее - постарайтесь сначала поискать в [Google](https://google.com).

Ответ взял [отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) (первая ссылка в гугле)